# Posting Dynamic values as a request body

Tags: java, http-post, azure-functions, azure-databricks

I am fetching the ID from some other API hitting the endpoint of that API.
I am fetching Dynamic ID from that API.
Now, In this code I which have posted I should send a request body that should accept dynamic ID that I am fetching from other API which I am storing in **str** and Iterate till the length of the ID and get JSON response for each ID.

```
   for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++) 
   {         
   str.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
   }
   for(String s:str)
   {
    HttpPost request1 = new HttpPost("/2.0/clusters/events");
    //StringEntity params=new StringEntity(array[i]);

    ***StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{\"id\":\"+s+\"}");*** 
    //main concern to send dynamic ID as a body  

    request1.addHeader("Authorization",bearerToken);
    request1.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");          
    request1.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
    request1.setEntity(params);
    System.out.println(params);
    HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(request1);
    System.out.println("Response Code:" + 
    response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    String json1 = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());
    System.out.println(json1);
    JSONObject event = new JSONObject(json1);
    JSONArray arrays=event.getJSONArray("events");
    for (int k=0;k< arrays.length();k++){
    JSONObject ids = arrays.getJSONObject(k);
    System.out.println(ids.get("id").toString()); 
    System.out.println(ids.get("timestamp").toString()); 
    System.out.println(ids.get("type").toString()); 
    System.out.println(ids.get("details").toString()); 
    }
    }
```

**The main question is how to send an value dynamically as a request body using String Entity or any other using JAVA.**
I should fetch the ID and Its repose for each ID till its length.

Comment: Hi, may I know if my answer and Jack's answer below helps your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how to use StringEntity to store your request parameter. You can use it as below:

```
StringEntity param = new StringEntity("id=" + s);
```

Sorry if I misunderstood your question, if so please tell me some more details of your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Hury's answer is almost right. But as you want to send a JSON string, then you should:

```
StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{\"id\":\""+ s + "\"}");
```

You can check it by `params.writeTo(System.out);`

Or use org.json library:

```
StringEntity params =new StringEntity(new org.json.JSONObject().put("id",s).toString());
```

Both of the methods above will output a string like the following:

```
{"id":"aaaa"}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

jsonObj.put("id", s);

request1.setEntity(jsonObj);